# how to maintain the image quality in browser

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background, image-quality, html

I have designed an arrow shape image(100px*25px) in Photoshop. I am using that image in HTML label background. I have written CSS to change image width dynamically.but its sharpness changing when label width reduces.so how I can maintain the original quality as per width changes.

Comment: Hi user3148335, I would suggest asking this question to http://stackoverflow.com/ as this deals with coding. When asking this type of question, it is best to include the CSS you're using for the image. You could put all of the code into a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: i tried svg format also,but when i reduce image width then sharpness decreasing.so what should i do to maintain the image. quality .

Answer (score 1):

If the image is *raster* (JPG, PNG or GIF) then there is nothing you can do. If you specify dimensions in the CSS different from the actual dimensions of the image source, then the browser will need to do some re-sampling be able to render the image at the requested dimensions. The reason for this is that the browsers need to make up missing pixels if you specify larger dimensions or  condense the pixels if you specify smaller dimensions. Different browsers and devices are bound to have different re-sampling algorithms, so you are bound to have a myriad of different user experiences.

If the image is *vector* (SVG), though, then you will always have a sharp-ish result. The reason for the "ish" is that, depending on the dimensions and the art, the browser might need to do some anti-aliasing in order to render fractional pixel shapes.

Comment: How I can convert into svg format in Photoshop.

Comment: @user3148335: Take a look at this link. It might help: http://creativedroplets.com/generate-svg-with-photoshop-cc-beta/

Comment: i tried svg format also,but when i reduce image width then sharpness decreasing.so what should i do to maintain the image. quality .

Answer (score 0):

Rescaling a rasterized image is usually not the best way to go in this situation.  I would consider taking your shape into illustrator and saving it as an SVG, which you can then use .

Alternatively, if you are hell-bent on keeping your rasterized arrow, you could experiment with the image rendering css property.

Try this in your css

```
.your-image-class {
  image-rendering: crisp-edges;
}
```

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering

Comment: Just a small comment, please notice that this property is only partially supported: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-crisp-edges

Comment: i tried svg format also,but when i reduce image width then sharpness decreasing.so what should i do to maintain the image. quality .